# How to run a function in Electron from renderer process in main?

Tags: javascript, webpack, electron

I am currently writing some simple plugin framework for electron. I require the files in the renderer process. This works great for UI elements but I wanted to add a plugin that runs an express server during startup. This works as long as the `BrowserWindow` is still visible. Once I close it, the server shuts down. This pretty much indicates that the server has been created on the renderer process.

The idea that I had was to export a function called `executeFunction` in my `main.js` file, the file that uses electron to start up. It simply calls the function passed to it. I then imported the file using `const { executeFunction } = require('electron').remote.require('./main')` and passed my `setupServer` function to it.

For some odd reasons, it still gets called on renderer even though I pass it to the main process before calling the function.

Any idea if what I am trying to do is even possible?

Here are the relevant code snippets:

```
export function executeFunction(externalFunction) {
    try {
        externalFunction();
        log.warn(`running on renderer? ${isRenderer}`);
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

Here is the server setup code:

```
import express from 'express';
import graphqlHttp from 'express-graphql';
import {
    buildSchema
} from 'graphql';

const { app } = require('electron').remote;
const {executeFunction} = require('electron').remote.require('./main');
import log from 'electron-log';
import isRen from 'is-electron-renderer';

export default function setupServer() {
    const schema = buildSchema(`
    type Query {
        hello: String
    }
`);

    const root = {
        hello: () => {
            return 'Hello World!';
        },
    };

    const expressApp = express();
    expressApp.use('/graphql', graphqlHttp({
        schema,
        rootValue: root,
        graphiql: true,
    }));
    log.warn(`is renderer ${isRen}`);
    const server = expressApp.listen(4000);
    log.warn('listening on port 4000');

    // make sure to close the server on window-closed
    app.on('quit', () => {
        log.warn('app is closing, shutting down server');
        server.close()
    });
}

// start server
executeFunction(() => {
    setupServer();
});
```

Comment: Do you still have the default 'window-all-closed' listener in place which quit's the hole app?

Comment: Yes. It checks if I am not running on OSX and quits the app. I test it on a Macbook though. So closing the BrowserWindow won't quit the app (as it still shows in the dock). But the server is down. That's why I assumed it started on the renderer thread.
I also added two log statements that print if the current thread is the renderer thread. Within `executeFunction` I get `false`, meaning that I am on the main thread. But I added the statement to the `setupServer` method too and there it prints `true`.

Comment: I would suggest you take a look at this https://github.com/hokein/electron-sample-apps/blob/master/crash-report/main.js sample app. It creates a http-Server within the Main-Process and awaits a http request from the render process. Futhermore take a look at remote api description https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/remote.md. Passing callbacks to the main process via remote has some draw backs.